# ASP.Net MVC Upload file using jquery-form plugin and returning a Json result

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ajax, json, forms

I'm trying to use the JQuery Form plugin (http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) to upload a file and a couple extra fields from my view, and I want the action method to return a Json result to the javascript callback.

Currently, the ActionMethod is called correctly (I can process the files and fields from the form) but when I return the Json result the browser tries to download it as a file (If I download the file and see its contents, it's the JSON content that I am returning.).

This is my form:

```
<form id="FormNewFile" action="@Url.Content("~/Home/AddFile")" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="eventId" value="25" />
    <input type="text" name="description" />
    <input type="file" name="fileName" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send!" />
</form>
```

This is my javascript:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
        $("#FormNewFile").ajaxForm({
           dataType:'json',
           success:processJson
     });
     });

     function processJson(a,b) {
        alert('success');
     }
  </script>
```

And this is my ActionMethod:

```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult AddFile(long? eventId, string description)
   {
      int id = 5;
      return Json(new {id});
   }
```

The name of the file the browser tries to download is something like AddFilee87ce48e, with the last 8 characters being random hexadecimal characters.

And finally, the content of the file downloaded is:

{"id":5}

And the processJson function in javascript never gets called.

I googled a lot and the only thing that seems to work is returning the JSON result as a "Content" result from the action method, I think that's the approach I'm gonna take, but I still want to know why this isn't working?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What I ended up doing was manually serializing the object I wanted to return as JSON, if I do this then the response won't have a header, therefore it will be handled by javascript instead of the browser. I used this helper method:

```
  public static ActionResult JsonPlain(object x)
  {
     var result = new ContentResult();
     result.Content = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(x);
     return result;
  }
```

Hope this helps someone else

Comment: Thanx willvv, that did the trick. I was only getting this issue in IE9

Comment: +1 @willw, thanks for that. Has also solved the and issue I was having where IE9 wants to download the JSON response.

Answer (score 4):

That's normal behavior. [Excerpt from the documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload):

> Since it is not possible to upload
>   files using the browser's
>   XMLHttpRequest object, the Form Plugin
>   uses a hidden iframe element to help
>   with the task. This is a common
>   technique, but it has inherent
>   limitations. The iframe element is
>   used as the target of the form's
>   submit operation which means that the
>   server response is written to the
>   iframe. This is fine if the response
>   type is HTML or XML, but doesn't work
>   as well if the response type is script
>   or JSON, both of which often contain
>   characters that need to be repesented
>   using entity references when found in
>   HTML markup.
>
> To account for the challenges of
>   script and JSON responses, the Form
>   Plugin allows these responses to be
>   embedded in a textarea element and it
>   is recommended that you do so for
>   these response types when used in
>   conjuction with file uploads. Please
>   note, however, that if there is no
>   file input in the form then the
>   request uses normal XHR to submit the
>   form (not an iframe). This puts the
>   burden on your server code to know
>   when to use a textarea and when not
>   to. If you like, you can use the
>   iframe option of the plugin to force
>   it to always use an iframe mode and
>   then your server can always embed the
>   response in a textarea. The following
>   response shows how a script should be
>   returned from the server:

This means that if you want to return JSON you need to wrap it in a `<textarea>` tags on your server. To achieve this you could write a custom action result deriving from [JsonResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult.aspx) and wrapping the generated JSON inside those tags.

Comment: Yep, I saw that, but I just didn't understand the <textarea> section. What's the response type that I should use? Also, as I posted on my question, if I just serialize the object and send a Content response with the JSON (without the <textarea>) it works, therefore it seems to be something related with the Json result response type.

Answer (score 1):

The following blog post, [jQuery File Upload in ASP.NET MVC without using Flash](http://aspzone.com/tech/jquery-file-upload-in-asp-net-mvc-without-using-flash/), addresses the issue of wrapping the response in a textarea as described by Darin Dimitrov's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the action on your form tag:

```
action="@Url.Content("~/Home/AddFile")"
```

The only usage I've seen of this is in script tags such as :

```
<script language="javascript" src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js")%>
```

The correct reference for the action would be:

```
action="/Home/Addfile"
```

While I am not too sure about the explanation as to why but the UrlHelper:

```
Url.Content("~/somepath")
```

converts a virtual path to a absolute path and expects a physical file such as a javascript.

The json result might be being returned as a file download because the mvc framework is expecting a file download of some description. Just as:

```
<a href="<%= Url.Content("~/_docs/folder/folder/document.pdf") %>">
document.pdf</a>
```

would download or display a physical pdf file.

Comment: You're right in that Url.Content isn't meant to do that, but in the end it generates action="Home/Addfile", so it doesn't make any difference. It is actually trying to download the file because when you return a JsonResult it adds a JSON header, and the browser tries to process all responses with a header.

Answer (score 0):

My solution using json and no specific javascript:

```
/// <summary>
/// A result to use in combination with jquery.ajax.form when we want to upload a file using ajax
/// </summary>
public class FileJsonResult : JsonResult
{
    public JsonResult Result { get; set; }

    public FileJsonResult(JsonResult result):base()
    {
        this.Result = result;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.Write("<textarea>");
        this.Result.ExecuteResult(context);
        context.HttpContext.Response.Write("</textarea>");
        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
    }
}
```